# I cannot get values from my FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error when I run the program:
com.cdirect.agenda2.AllEvents$1.onDataChange(AllEvents.java:47)
-`Events events = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);`

I want to get all data from my FirebaseDatabase. I created Events.java. It has getter and setters. MyAdapter is adapting for RecyclerView on AllEvents.java. I want to show all data on AllEvents.java.
But I cannot success. Can you help me?

MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Events> list;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Events> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.evententry,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Events events = list.get(position);
    holder.plan.setText(events.getPlan());
    holder.note.setText(events.getNote());
    holder.date.setText(events.getDate());
    holder.time.setText(events.getTime());
    holder.remb.setText(events.getRemb());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView id, plan, note, date, time, remb;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIdCard);
        plan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlanCard);
        note = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNoteCard);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateCard);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCard);
        remb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRememberCard);
    }
}
```

MyEvents.java

```
public class AllEvents extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Events> list;
DatabaseReference dbRef;
MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(AllEvents.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_events);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                Events events = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);
                list.add(events);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Events.java

```
public class Events {
String id;
String plan;
String note;
String date;
String time;
String remb;

public Events(String id, String plan, String note, String date, String time, String remb) {
    this.id = id;
    this.plan = plan;
    this.note = note;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.remb = remb;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPlan() {
    return plan;
}
public void setPlan(String plan) {
    this.plan = plan;
}
public String getNote() {
    return note;
}
public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public String getRemb() {
    return remb;
}
public void setRemb(String remb) {
    this.remb = remb;
}
}
```

My Database is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1AjR.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, can you share your Database Structure?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine yes. I'm editing in minutes

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo In which class should I add this code?

Comment: Inside the `onCancelled` method.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added it but I cannot find any error in logcat

Comment: Does `events.getPlan()` return the correct data inside `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't know but I get to this error :(  at com.cdirect.agenda2.AllEvents$1.onDataChange(AllEvents.java:48)
Events events = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AlexMamo I cannot see that on Logcat screen.

Comment: Where does this `com.cdirect.agenda2.AllEvents$1.onDataChange(AllEvents.java:48)` come from?

Comment: @AlexMamo It comes from Events class. It has getter and setters. I shared codes in this post

Answer (score 0):

First try to make them private for the `Event` class.

```
private String id;
private String plan;
private String note;
private String date;
private String time;
private String remb;
```

Second, change `adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);` line to here. Additional here, you need handle when`onCancelled` also.

```
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
            Events events = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);
            list.add(events);
        }
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.i("???", "onCancelled Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```